# Get serial number or other unique ID of MIDI device?

Tags: android, kotlin, midi

If I have an Android [MidiDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiDevice) object, I can get its name or product name like this:

```
val name = device.info.properties.getString(MidiDeviceInfo.PROPERTY_NAME)
val product = device.info.properties.getString(MidiDeviceInfo.PROPERTY_PRODUCT)
```

But a request for its [serial number](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/midi/MidiDeviceInfo#PROPERTY_SERIAL_NUMBER) always returns null:

```
val serialNumber = device.info.properties.getString(MidiDeviceInfo.PROPERTY_SERIAL_NUMBER)
```

This is happening with every device I've tried, including virtual MIDI devices, USB MIDI interfaces and Bluetooth MIDI interfaces. Is this working for anyone else? I didn't find any mention of this property in Google, StackOverflow or the Android IssueTracker.

My goal in showing the serial number is to distinguish in the interface between multiple interfaces of the same model. I'm open to other solutions if there's another way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to Android specifically, but it's rare for MIDI interfaces to have such a serial number.

This is a common problem.  If you look at the USB device descriptor (using USBTreeView or similar) for multiple of the same model of the device, you'll see that there is often nothing distinguishing between the two.

Additionally, on the MIDI side of things, there is certainly no guarantee of ID/serial as there isn't even a standard for retrieving such information.  I think out of all the MIDI devices I own, only one (APC40) has a serial number accessible via SysEx messages.

All this to say, I don't think that property is going to be reliably populated because there is no device-specific information to base it on in most cases.  It might have been added to the Android API for something like RTP-MIDI or similar.

Comment: Thanks. iOS has kMIDIPropertyUniqueID which is populated with a large integer, but I don't know where that comes from.

Comment: @arlomedia Probably from the OS, rather than the device.  Maybe a hash of the USB device path?  I think Windows does some hash like that.